# Need to restore sp site in sharepoint 2013 testing environment

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, central-administration, administration

Hope all are doing well.

I need to restore sp public facing website from production to testing environment.

for this purpose I have taken the backup of Production site using central administration and I copied that backup file to my testing environment.

there is already another web application we have in port80 of testing environment which I dont want to delete it.

So I have created a new web application and then I have created one site collection (url: http//mytestingsite)

so if I want to restore what I have to do now?
I know SP powershell command to restore the site collection.

but one more thing our production environment site have cross site publishing and it's available in 2 different languages.

So whatever I have followed are right steps?
and if right then while restoring which url I have to mention? Web or site collection??

I highly appreciate and always thankful if anyone can explain me the easiest process to do it from starting.

Thanks in advance.